# InvalidArgumentException The current node list is empty

Tags: php, laravel, web, web-scraping, atom-editor

i am trying web scraping so i get this error on "\vendor\symfony\dom-crawler\Crawler.php:552"
here is the crawler.php code what the browser showed me:

- @throws \InvalidArgumentException When current node is empty

  */

  public function text(string $default = null, bool $normalizeWhitespace = true): string

  {

  ```
   if (!$this->nodes) {

       if (null !== $default) {

           return $default;

       }



       throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The current node list is empty.');

   }



   $text = $this->getNode(0)->nodeValue;



   if ($normalizeWhitespace) {

       return trim(preg_replace('/(?:\s{2,}+|[^\S ])/', ' ', $text));

   }



   return $text;
  ```

  }

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when trying to access the text of an empty node list. I have written a util class for this purpose, as I don't always mind the value being empty. Simply pass the node list you want to get the inner text from, like so `CrawlUtil::innerText($nodeList)`. Hope it will help somebody in the future :)

```php
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

class CrawlUtil
{

    /**
     * Suppresses exception that node list is empty.
     *
     * @param Crawler $crawler
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public static function innerText(Crawler $crawler): ?string
    {

        if ($crawler->count() > 0 && $crawler->text() !== '') {
            return $crawler->innerText();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```